# _destroy isn't working in Coocon gem with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I have the same issue as this
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471777/accept-nested-attributes-for-allow-destroy-destroy-not-working)

But that solution didn't help me.
Here are my strong params:

```html
def request_params
   params.require(:request).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :mobile, :type,
     :filled_cartridges_attributes => [:cartridge_name,:client_id,,
    :count,:_destroy,:id],
```

So i have :_destroy and :id. The guy in the previous forgot to add :id to strong params. Adding an id solved his problem.

Here is my request model:

```html
has_many :filled_cartridges, inverse_of: :request, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_cartridges, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

And this is how params look like after submitting:

```html
request: 
...some params....
filled_cartridges_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    '0': !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
      cartridge_name: HP LaserJet3000
      _destroy: 'false'
      id: '1'
    '2': !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
     cartridge_name: new 9
     _destroy: '1'
     id: '13'
```

Here the 2nd one should be destroyed. 
But it doesn't.

Comment: How do you assign params to the model?

Comment: @BroiSatse what do you mean?

Comment: You got your params in your controller, but what do you do with them? Could you show the controller action? Also, is the first object updated?

Comment: @BroiSatse, My controller method has too much of code not related to the destroy. In update action i update the fields, and it works, but there is no code for deleting, as I understood it should delete automatically due to _destroy param. The gem cocoon doesn't tell anything about it. In railscasts tutorials lecturer said that it destroys automatically if _destroy is provided. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, providing you are using `filled_cartridges_attributes=` method (which is internally used by `assign_params` and other methods). This will only mark associated record for destruction, it will not destroy model until you call `save` on it, so the way you assign your params is important.

Comment: @BroiSatse, yep i have .save in my method. Also i noticed one thing. Records that are marked to be deleted change their id's in DB. ex: 19,20,21 ids changed to 22,23,24 ids. I mean 3 records marked to destroy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76023/discussion-between-broisatse-and-user3565829).

Answer (score 0):

You should add :_destroy and :id on your permitted parameters to the specified nested attribute.